# PHP Laravel encoding problem with uploaded file name

Tags: php, laravel

There are sometimes issues with my Laravel application on uploading files with umlauts in their filename. So I'd like to convert the filenames before uploading (e.g. Ä becomes Ae). This would be very easy with a simple `str_replace`. However, it seems that there are some issues with the encoding of the uploaded filename. To localize the exact problem, I tried the following things.

`echo $file->getClientOriginalName();` outputs **Änderung.pdf**

However, the following lines return false:

```php
if ($file->getClientOriginalName() == "Änderung.pdf") {
  return true;
else {
  return false;
}
```

When I output every char of `$file->getClientOriginalName();` it looks like A � � n d e r u n g . p d f

But `mb_detect_encoding($file->getClientOriginalName());` outputs `UTF-8`.

It seems like the filename is UTF-8 and can output umlauts, however the filename's Ä is not a real Ä. Could you please help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Start by checking what the byte values of those two � actually are. (F.e. via a debug output using `urlencode`.)

Comment: On uploading **Änderung.pdf** …
`urlencode($file->getClientOriginalName())` returns A%CC%88nderung.pdf  | 
`urlencode("Änderung.pdf")` returns %C3%84nderung.pdf

Comment: `0xCC 0x88` is a _Combining Diaeresis_. If you want to match that specifically to replace these characters, then you need to see to it that you are using the correct byte values in what you are trying to replace (could be done f.e. using `chr`.) But a more general solution might perhaps make more sense, there’s probably libraries out there to _normalize_ the different ways such a character can be represented in Unicode/UTF-8.